# Tarpaulin vs PVC Roofing Sheet for Budged Project

Tags: cover

So I have this [gazebo/cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHLdv.jpg) in the garden, which served me proudly for almost 2 years and then some female named storm came and f****d it for me.
The top sheet was torn away, but the gazebo under it is still standing strong apart from one broken support beam, which I can easily fix.

Now I want to up my game and build something better on a tight budget.
The frame will be timber, looking something like this: https://skfb.ly/6vJPC
Btw this is an exact replica of my back garden.

My questions are:
Do I go with [PVC Roofing Sheets](http://www.diy.com/departments/translucent-pvc-roofing-sheet-2-4m-x-660mm/35459_BQ.prd) or [Heavy Duty 650gsm Tarpaulin](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Tarpaulin-Extra-Heavy-Duty-PVC-Fabric-650gsm-Tarp-Truck-Trailer-Boat-Cover/253306489008?hash=item3afa3e48b0:m:m92zpsEPAyk1rmJCHXADhFw)? Which will hold its ground better in strong winds?
I am thinking of using a stapler gun to attach the tarpaulin, but if I go with the PVC sheets what kind of screws or nails are suitable?
What is the best way to waterproof the ends touching the brick walls, so that no water drips down the walls?
What size timber should I use? 50x50mm is enough/weak/overkill? Longest single piece will be 2600mm.
Do you see any flaws with my frame design?
Any other suggestions/comments?

Thank you.

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges. Do you want a transparent roof or no? What are the requirements of the roof? (I'd never use a tarp for a roof anyway. They're for woodpiles and temporary use, and they'll leak if stapled.)

Comment: Don't need it to be transparent as I already have a gazebo underneath. I will put a little blob of silicone where the staples are, so it won't leak. The tarp is very thick, probably one of the thickest on the market. I used a cheap one (170gsm) for almost 2 years and it worked, so the 650gsm one should be ОК.